# VsHookCLRLoading error on startup of Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio

You all are my last hope before i have to have my machine reimaged. I'm running win10, VS2019 Enterprise.

I went to start up VS and i immediately got a popup with unknown error and telling me to go look at the activity log for my VS instance. I did so, and the text below is the only piece that seems lke an issue. Research into VsHookCLRLoading yielded very little, and most of it unanswered questions. I looked into the

---

tag 80004001, and that seems to be a catch all error for windows. attempting to limit it to VS was fruitless.

```
<entry>
<record>26</record>
<time>2020/03/25 12:51:23.422</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>Failure calling VsHookCLRLoading.</description>
<hr>80004001 - E_NOTIMPL</hr>
<errorinfo></errorinfo>
```

Does anyone have any info they can give me before i just wipe my machine?

Comment: Belongs to https://superuser.com/

Comment: I would wipe just the Visual Studio configuration to begin with. Also try reinstalling the .NET Framework, or repairing its current install. It could be some damaged file from it as the message substly suggests.

Answer (score -1):

What Does Error 80004001 Mean? It means that there are mis-configured files in your operating system or Your system failed to update applications and will show the error code 80004001.

Causes Of Error Code 80004001:

The error 80004001 is very general and has many reasons but mostly related to

1. Corrupted DLL files, VDX and EXE files
2. Adding wrong registry files on your computer
3. Corrupt system files for your operating system
   4.Incomplete installations of various applications on your computer

You can try first to reinstall or repair the VS

Check the source for more [here](https://www.get-itsolutions.com/fix-error-code-80004001-bluescreen/) .

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same error on trying to open VS 2022 and the following one when I was trying to open Discord:

```
Discord Not Opening Error Code (0xc0000135)
```

So I found the solution in the following video:

[Fix Discord Not Opening Error Code (0xc0000135) The Application Was Unable To Start Correctly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d5Ud8s2EMCY)

In a nutshell, activating Windows features on "Programs and Features" options, ".NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).